# Массив строк в структуре

Tags: c, массивы, строки

```
/* Есть структура */

typedef struct {

    const char **links;

} strings;


int main() {
    
    strings S;
    
    const char *arr[] = {"abc", "def"};
    
    /* Почему можно сделать так */
    
    S.links = arr;
    
    /* И нельзя сделать так? */
    
    S.links = {"abc", "def"};
}
```

Comment: Определитесь с языком, С или С++?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, C. Надеялся привлечь больше внимания к вопросу, добавив вторую метку.

Comment: Похоже вы хотите, чтобы правая сторона выражения `S.links = {"abc", "def"};` каким-то образом оказывалась временным массивом и потом неявно приводилась к указателю на указатель. Даже если бы это могло как-то прокатить, где по-вашему хранился бы массив, указатель на первый элемент которого присваивался бы `S.links`.

Comment: @user7860670, да, действительно. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первом варианте

```
S.links = arr;
```

полю `links` присваивается массив. Массивы автоматически переводятся в тип указатель на первый элемент если надо. В вашем случае `char const *[]` => `char const **`. То есть `S.links` указывают на `arr`. *Это не копирование, а ссылка.*

Во втором случае

```
S.links = {"abc", "def"};
```

вы создаёте структуру неизвестного типа или массив чего-то и хотите куда-то присвоить. Сначала нужно указать тип вашего объекта `{"abc", "def"}`. Например такой :

```
S.links = (const char *[]){"abc", "def"};
```

У вас создаётся временный массив указателей на строки. И массив переконвертируется в адрес первого элемента. Теперь `S.links` хранит адрес этого массива. *Этот массив как временный объект будет храниться в стеке и адрес будет неадекватен при выходе из функции.*

В обоих случаях вы создаёте *временный* массив до выхода из функции и берёте адрес *временного* массива. Никакого копирования строк не будет.

Comment: Всё чётко и ясно, благодарю!

Comment: Вообще-то язык не допускает взятия адреса временного массива. А временные объекты обычно не переживают выражения.

Comment: у меня всё берётся, посмотрите  https://godbolt.org/z/WY534n надо как-то поискать в стандарте это.  @user7860670

Comment: стандарт C11 6.5.2.5 / 5 : "Значение составного литерала-это значение неназванного объекта, инициализированного списком инициализаторов. Если составной литерал находится вне тела функции, объект имеет статическую длительность хранения; в противном случае он имеет автоматическую длительность хранения, связанную с блоком-оболочкой." @user7860670